# How to parse custom datetime string

Tags: datetime, go

I have nginx log file which I need to parse using Go, the format of date time is

```
dd/Month/yyyy:HH:MM:SS
```

For eg

```
26/Jul/2020:16:49:28
```

I need to convert this to a date object. How can I do this ?

Comment: What have you tried? Perhaps something from the [time](https://golang.org/pkg/time/) package?

Comment: @Rsm-What about `zone`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UTC time:

```
s := "26/Jul/2020:16:49:28"
t, err := time.Parse("02/Jan/2006:15:04:05", s)
fmt.Println(t, err)
```

Output ([playground](https://play.golang.org/p/AKSLJ5xMCcJ)):

```
2020-07-26 16:49:28 +0000 UTC <nil>
```

`layout` options([src/time/format.go](https://golang.org/src/time/format.go)):

[image]